# Sound fluctuation on Windows 8.1 while dual screening + Windows Apps

Tags: audio, video, multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, hdmi

I want to keep this as detailed as possible because I am unable to resolve this really annoying issue. Before I get into the issue, let me run down what my setup is:

- Alienware 14 with Microsoft Windows 8.1 6.3.9600 Build 9600 x64
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
- 8GB RAM
- Bios: Alienware A04, 8/12/2013
- Sound: NVIDIA Virtual Audio Device (Wave Extensible) (WDM)
- Realtek High Definition Audio
- Dolby Surround Sound Home Theatre V4

---

Whenever I am doing anything, I am usually connected to a second monitor so I can watch movies and whatnot on one screen while playing my games or surfing the web on the primary screen. I use an HDMI to DVI-I cable, so the audio comes out of the laptop speakers. Let's say I'm watching a movie on Netflix, and I pull up a game such as Minecraft (in Windowed Mode), the volume in Netflix drops down about 80%. Now this makes sense to me, since anything you do on the primary screen should take priority; however, I have the PC option of changing the volume in the communications tab off and it still does this. I also have the feature disabled that allows PC apps to take control of the audio, yet it still turns down the audio. Now the audio does not drop when I'm running netflix first then minecraft; however, when I do it the other way around the audio is decreased in Netflix.

Now, another annoying issue that related to this is when playing PC games where there are CGI trailers and actual gameplay audio. Let's take, for instance, Metal Gear Rising Revengeance. Whenever I play that game, when it hits a CGI Cutscene, the audio is at full capacity; however, whenever I play the actual game the audio is decreased. To me these issues sound related so that is why I threw these together. (I did not have a dual monitor connected while playing MGR:R)

Now I have looked for a solution for this for quite some time. I haven't been able to find one, though there is a possibility I could just miss something so I do apologize ahead of time if this has been posted before.

Following did not solve my issue: 
**Sound > Communication > Do Nothing**
**Speaker Properties > Advanced > Exclusive Mode > Unchecked** *Allow Applications To Take Exclusive Controls of This Device*

Those are the only two steps I could find that would mess around with the audio.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a "feature" that in some cases(like phone call) it lovers sound volume to 80 %. Go to Control Panel-->Sound and after "Communications" tab. Change there setting to "Do nothing".

Also there is link with images: http://www.aura-clan.co.uk/forum/index.php?topic=314.0

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Vasili111 for your response but the radio button in the Communications tab for Sound already has 'Do Nothing' selected. I mentioned that already up above. That wouldn't be the solution.